# Tobit panel data or panel data with truncated dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, tobit-regression

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the Tobit model and the data panels model together, especially in the R language?

I tried the `censReg` package, but it didn't address the inherent testing of models in data panels.

Comment: Maybe Honoré (1992) Trimmed LAD and least squares estimation of truncated and censored regression models with fixed effects. Implemented in R's plm `pldv` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate Tobit regresssions with random intercepts with the censReg package and with the pldv command of the plm package.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any document about It?

Comment: @VitorDeVasconcelosLima You may want to check out the package documentation. If you have the `plm` package installed, run: `?plm::pldv`